# SSRS: Adding Column headers that have multi-row descriptions

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-data-tools, reportbuilder3.0

I wish to have multi-row Column headers on a table, per this image:
[image]

I have tried this:

- Inserting another table into the column header, so it is a nested table.

  - > Result: second header row repeats for every Data row, because the nested table is also bound to the dataset.
- Use separate tables, 1st for the headers(bound to a 1 record dataset) and 2nd for the data (which has no headers). Then just lined them up to look like one table.

  - > Result: Does not carry the header across pages. Which is required.

I am using SSDT in Visual studio 2017 to build the report.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click the existing header row and "Insert New Row" e.g.

[image: SSRS Insert New Row]

Then select cells and use the "Merge Cells" for your first header row.